# Switch from Google Analytics to Google Tagmanager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to switch from the hard-coded GA tag to only using Tag Manager, but I'm unsure whether I will get the same data from the Pageview-tag in the Tagmanager as the GA code-snippet.

Does anyone know if only the Pageview-tag from Google Tagmanager provides the same data (like session-duration, source, etc.) as the Google Analytics script itself? Or do I need to fire a tag for every type of data I normally see in Google Analytics?

Sorry for my broken english, I hope my question still makes sense :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are currently only send pageviews from hardcoded, sending it from GTM will give you the same data.

Those you are talking about are processing that Google Analytics does. You don't send time on page or session duration, you send pageviews (and events, if you've configured them) and then Google Analytics calculates those metrics.